# How to change journal mode in SQLite using preprocessor macros at compile-time

Tags: sqlite, macros

As the question suggests, I want to compile Sqlite library with the option:
`journal_mode = OFF` as well as `synchronous = OFF`.

I am trying to stop the `journal mode` creation (or use `journal_mode = memory`) as well as `synchronous` to measure SQLite performance.

I know that `PRAGMA synchronous = OFF` and `PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF` can be used at runtime to do that but I need to do it at compile time.

Is there any SQLite preprocessor macro or flag to do that at compile time?

Example:

`PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON`  (Pragma)

`SQLITE_DEFAULT_FOREIGN_KEYS=1`  (Preprocessor macro)

Answer (score 1):

SQLite has many [compilation options](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html), but ones for changing the default of the [journal_mode](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode) or [synchronous](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_synchronous) PRAGMAs are not among them.